# Tags with asterisks are not displayed in the new navigation

Tags: bug, tags, tag-watching, new-nav

I have tags with asterisks in my favorites, like **c#-*** and ***xaml***, in addition to normal tags like **c#** and **wpf**. Previously they worked correctly in the new navigation, but now they cause a couple of issues in the [list of questions filtered by favorite tags](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=needanswer&layout=expanded&tagFilter=favorite):

- Questions are filtered by all tags (for example, questions with just **c#-4.0** tag are included), but only tags without asterisks are displayed in the filter editor, page title and filter dropdown.

  *Expected:* all tags are displayed the filter editor, page title and filter dropdown.
- Questions which are included based on the tags with asterisks are highlighted, other questions are not.

  *Expected:* no questions are highlighted, because all of them are included in the filter.