# Tags should be sorted by popularity in the filter editor in the new navigation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, new-nav

Tags which are displayed at the top of the [page filtered by a tag with asterisks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*xaml*), with the new navigation enabled, are sorted alphabetically. It's inconvenient, because it doesn't let me see which tags are important and which are not, especially when there're many tags. Considering tags aren't even clickable (or hoverable), it's very annoying.

Tags should be sorted by popularity, like it's done in the old navigation (tag list sorted by popularity is displayed on the right in this case).

Also, questions are highlighted incorrectly in this case. See [a related bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257262/tags-with-asterisks-are-not-displayed-in-the-new-navigation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been completed and deployed with new nav alpha 2.